# Problema al obtener Datos de Firebase RealTime Database (kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin, realtime-database

El problema que tengo es que al momento de realizar la petición a la base de datos me debería retornar el valor, pero en este caso no me retorna nada. Al momento de realizar la simulación, la aplicación se ejecuta bien y al cargar la app en el smartphone no me retorna ningún valor. El problema es que no se como obtener las llaves autogeneradas por el `push(data)`, si me pueden guiar para solucionar esta falla les agradecería.

**Este es el MainActivity:**

'''

```
private lateinit var mdatabase: DatabaseReference

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    var btnget = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnGET)
    var txView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txView)

    mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("GPS").child("BaseDeDatos")
    btnget.setOnClickListener {
        val postListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    var latitud = dataSnapshot.child("latitud").getValue().toString()
                    txView.setText(latitud)
                }

            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
                Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
            }
        }
        mdatabase.addValueEventListener(postListener)
    }

}
```

}

'''
y aquí están los valores y el código en python para enviar los valores a firebase:

```
import pyrebase

config = {
  "apiKey": "*****",
  "authDomain": "**.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://******.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "*****.appspot.com"
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

data = {
       "latitud":2.9141772333333336,
       "longitud":79.02129898333334,
        }
print(data)
print("Enviando a base de datos")
db.child("GPS").child("BaseDeDatos").push(data)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de pulsar el button me sale un null en el textview y lo ideal es que me pueda mostrar los datos guardados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No recuerdo ahora si los nombres de nodos son *case sensitive* pero aunque no lo sean, esa `A` mayúscula rechina: **`BaseDeDAtos`**. Corrige eso, y si no funciona, depura dentro del listener el Snapshot completo y revisa lo que hay en él.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, al momento de obtener el dato me sale un null, sabes si tiene algo que ver que este guardando los datos de la siguiente forma:
 'db.child("GPS").child("BaseDeDatos").push(data)' no se si al momento de colocar asi como se genera un código eso le impide que me devuelva el dato

Comment: Por favor, especifica cada cosa: 1. ¿Corregiste el asunto de la `A`?, 2. ¿Qué depuraste y dónde (qué es lo que devuelve `null`)? 3. ¿Dónde dices guardar los datos así? Si es preciso pulsa en [edit] para agregar todo esto, de modo que nos ayudes a entender mejor el problema. Considera que debes tener a mano de algún modo la clave autogenerada, pues los datos están dentro de ella. ¿Tienes a mano esa clave autogenerada? ¿De dónde sale? ¿Cómo guardas la referencia a ella? Quizá conviene que expliques el proceso para guardar esos datos y lo que quieres hacer aquí exactamente.

Comment: Claro que realice el cambio, pero el problema es por las claves auto generadas no se como obtenerla para poder acceder a la longitud y latitud.  Aumente un par de cosas para hacerme entender espero que con eso me puedan ayudar

Comment: Esa llave autogenerada te la retorna `push`. Es decir, tú puedes recuperarla guardando una referencia a esta llamada: `db.child("GPS").child("BaseDeDatos").push(data)` Ahora bien, si tú quieres recuperarla a posteriori, quizá debas replantear tu forma de guardar los datos, porque va a ser harto difícil conocer esa clave fuera de un contexto de `push`. Por otro lado, no tiene demasiada utilidad querer recuperar los datos en ese contexto, pues serían los mismos datos que estás pasando en `data` (ahí ya tienes la latitud y la longitud). Yo intuyo que lo que ocurre aquí es un error de enfoque.